# Login Register Page for Anroid

Tags: database, android, login

I have a mysql database in server, storing user accounts information (username and password). I'm developing the Android login/ register page for an app.

When the app is first loaded on client mobile, should the Activity takes all the accounts information from the server and store in the local sqllite? and then when user clicks to login or register, no need to get the login information from server. Or I should make httpRequest with username and password pass to the server and get the httpResponse for successful login or not?

Wondering which method is better.

Comment: The only reason you would store login information on the client is if you wanted to provide an automatic login mechanism.

Comment: I've read this 5 times now and I still can't tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to achieve offline mode (a user can use application, when internet is not available), you can store information of the user in SQLite. This scenario can also be handled with one time authentication approach by generating a token and storing it into local storage on device.

Moreover, application is providing only online mode, than http request will be a good choice.